# Reset date value in antd datepicker(react-testing-library)

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd, react-testing-library

I want to test the functionality of clicking on the clear icon that appears on hovering on the antd datepicker but it's not working for me.

```
it('should clear start date', async () => {
        render(<Component />)
        const startDate = screen.getByPlaceholderText('SEARCH_START_DATE_PLACEHOLDER')
        // startDate.focus()
        fireEvent.mouseOver(startDate)
        const closeIcon = screen.getAllByRole('img', { name: 'close-circle' })[0]
        await act(async () => {
            await fireEvent.click(closeIcon)
        })
        console.log(startDate.getAttribute('value'), 'value')
        const endDate = screen.getByPlaceholderText("SEARCH_END_DATE_PLACEHOLDER");
        await fireEvent.mouseDown(endDate);
        await fireEvent.change(endDate, { target: { value: "2022-05-03" } });
        await act(async () => {
            fireEvent.click(document.querySelectorAll(".ant-picker-cell-selected")[0]);
        })
    })

Any help would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You should select the container of the icon, not the icon itself.

Change:

```
const closeIcon = screen.getAllByRole('img', { name: 'close-circle' })[0]
```

To:

```
const closeIcon = (screen.getAllByRole('img', { name: 'close-circle' })[0]).parentElement
```

Then, use mouseUp event instead of click event.

Change:

```
await fireEvent.click(closeIcon)
```

To:

```
await fireEvent.mouseUp(closeIcon)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say it's not working for you, what do you mean exactly? Is the clear button showing off but does nothing, or you cannot see the clear button at all? I think for the clear button to appear you must specify a defaultValue property on your DatePicker component.

Comment: If there is a need for supporting information, it should be asked in a comment to the question, not as a proposed answer.

Comment: Must have 50 reputation to comment to a question...

Comment: There is an initial value of the current date on it. And I am trying to clear this value by clicking on the clear icon. But it's not working.